# How know ASIFormDataRequest completed?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am using ASIFormDataRequest for the ios, I want to send data to server using POST method, so that in response to it, server will send me Json file. I was using NSURLConnection for the request using GET method, but now have to use for POST, and dont know, so is learning to use ASIFormDataRequest, but failed. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

ASIFormDataRequest has a method called

```
- (void) requestFinished : (AsiFormDataRequest*) request {
    NSString *myResponse = [request responseString]; // or do something else.
}
```

Also, you can set your own method to be called upon finish;

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithUrl:yourUrl];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(yourMethod:)];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

That being said, even more useful, is the first googlehit you get when searching for 'asiformdatarequest'as is shows http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use